# How to find images by similarity, inside a SQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, image, image-processing

I want to process images to establish say, 9 areas inside each one, then find the average color of each area, and then save it to a char field like this:

```
255,255,255,255,255,255,107,195,305
```

Then to find all the images similar to a given image, I have to calculate the distance between each pair of colors (comparing against the same areas), eg:

The difference between these images is 1:

```
255,255,255,255,255,255,107,195,305
255,255,255,255,255,255,107,195,304
```

The difference between these images is 3:

```
255,255,255,255,255,255,105,195,305
255,255,255,255,255,255,107,195,304
```

My problem is how do I perform such a query, and order it by similarity? The field is just a string, with values separated by commas.

Is it possible that a query like this could be fast? Or should I look for a different approach? We are talking about thousands of images

Edit: As @therealsix, one option could be to put each average color value into a separate column.

Comment: The only way I can perceive doing this within a query would be beyond ugly, and pretty guaranteed inefficient. It seems to me that it could be a reasonable query if this where 9 separate columns.

Comment: yes that was my first thought, I forgot to mention it. It looks like the best option so far. Thanks

Comment: See the answer I just posted.  All done in mysql on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using mysql functions to compare to your randomly given image.  First lets create a simple example table

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS images;

CREATE TABLE images (
  id         INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  rgb_values VARCHAR(255)
);
```

Now lets define the functions we will use in our query.  The first enables use to split the string on any delimiter and get the desired element back by index:

```
DROP FUNCTION SPLIT_STR;

CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(
  x VARCHAR(255),
  delim VARCHAR(12),
  pos INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN
  REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
  LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
  delim, '')
;
```

Next we define a function to calculate the image difference per your algorithm (or any algo for that matter you want to use):

```
DROP FUNCTION IMAGE_DIFF;

CREATE FUNCTION IMAGE_DIFF(
  from_val VARCHAR(255),
  to_val VARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS INTEGER(4)
RETURN
  ABS((SPLIT_STR(to_val, ',', 1) - SPLIT_STR(from_val, ',',1))) +
  ABS((SPLIT_STR(to_val, ',', 2) - SPLIT_STR(from_val, ',',2))) +
  ABS((SPLIT_STR(to_val, ',', 3) - SPLIT_STR(from_val, ',',3))) +
  ABS((SPLIT_STR(to_val, ',', 4) - SPLIT_STR(from_val, ',',4))) +
  ABS((SPLIT_STR(to_val, ',', 5) - SPLIT_STR(from_val, ',',5))) +
  ABS((SPLIT_STR(to_val, ',', 6) - SPLIT_STR(from_val, ',',6))) +
  ABS((SPLIT_STR(to_val, ',', 7) - SPLIT_STR(from_val, ',',7))) +
  ABS((SPLIT_STR(to_val, ',', 8) - SPLIT_STR(from_val, ',',8))) +
  ABS((SPLIT_STR(to_val, ',', 9) - SPLIT_STR(from_val, ',',9)))
;
```

Let's create some sample data:

```
INSERT INTO images(rgb_values) VALUES ("237,128,73,69,35,249,199,183,178");
INSERT INTO images(rgb_values) VALUES ("39,212,164,170,202,49,93,77,145");
INSERT INTO images(rgb_values) VALUES ("28,242,83,167,92,161,115,38,108");
INSERT INTO images(rgb_values) VALUES ("72,81,73,2,77,109,177,204,120");
INSERT INTO images(rgb_values) VALUES ("165,149,106,248,39,26,167,237,139");
INSERT INTO images(rgb_values) VALUES ("183,40,156,131,120,19,71,88,69");
INSERT INTO images(rgb_values) VALUES ("138,136,112,36,69,245,130,196,24");
INSERT INTO images(rgb_values) VALUES ("1,194,153,107,16,102,164,154,74");
INSERT INTO images(rgb_values) VALUES ("172,161,17,179,140,244,23,219,115");
INSERT INTO images(rgb_values) VALUES ("166,151,48,62,154,227,44,21,201");
INSERT INTO images(rgb_values) VALUES ("118,73,212,180,150,64,254,177,68");
INSERT INTO images(rgb_values) VALUES ("119,220,226,254,14,175,123,11,134");
INSERT INTO images(rgb_values) VALUES ("118,93,238,31,77,36,105,151,216");
INSERT INTO images(rgb_values) VALUES ("123,108,177,136,9,24,119,175,88");
INSERT INTO images(rgb_values) VALUES ("11,207,12,215,215,80,101,213,143");
INSERT INTO images(rgb_values) VALUES ("132,158,46,188,7,245,241,126,214");
INSERT INTO images(rgb_values) VALUES ("167,238,186,86,109,164,219,199,238");
INSERT INTO images(rgb_values) VALUES ("216,93,139,246,153,39,226,152,143");
INSERT INTO images(rgb_values) VALUES ("98,229,7,203,230,224,57,154,252");
INSERT INTO images(rgb_values) VALUES ("7,95,145,120,35,6,116,240,64");
INSERT INTO images(rgb_values) VALUES ("45,194,172,223,96,168,18,4,215");
INSERT INTO images(rgb_values) VALUES ("243,161,214,235,134,190,207,63,127");
INSERT INTO images(rgb_values) VALUES ("74,189,249,85,148,169,65,3,81");
INSERT INTO images(rgb_values) VALUES ("46,113,191,20,108,139,60,249,6");
INSERT INTO images(rgb_values) VALUES ("153,246,189,175,5,125,9,197,160");
INSERT INTO images(rgb_values) VALUES ("202,248,23,59,81,175,197,180,114");
INSERT INTO images(rgb_values) VALUES ("73,136,252,137,222,197,118,64,69");
INSERT INTO images(rgb_values) VALUES ("172,224,251,32,154,175,201,33,14");
INSERT INTO images(rgb_values) VALUES ("141,126,112,12,45,214,243,127,49");
INSERT INTO images(rgb_values) VALUES ("116,155,23,205,62,235,111,136,205");
```

and then run a query using our newly defined function against the image you want to compare with:

```
mysql> SELECT id
    ->      , image_diff(rgb_values, '255,191,234,123,85,23,255,255,255') rgb_diff
    ->   FROM images
    ->  ORDER BY 2 DESC;
+----+----------+
| id | rgb_diff |
+----+----------+
| 19 |     1150 |
| 10 |     1148 |
|  3 |     1122 |
| 27 |     1094 |
|  9 |     1070 |
| 15 |     1069 |
| 23 |     1061 |
| 21 |     1059 |
|  7 |     1034 |
| 12 |     1024 |
| 24 |     1022 |
| 30 |     1016 |
| 29 |      989 |
| 28 |      962 |
|  2 |      947 |
|  4 |      933 |
| 16 |      893 |
|  6 |      885 |
|  8 |      875 |
| 20 |      848 |
| 25 |      835 |
| 26 |      815 |
|  1 |      777 |
| 22 |      758 |
| 14 |      745 |
| 11 |      706 |
| 18 |      683 |
|  5 |      656 |
| 13 |      645 |
| 17 |      494 |
+----+----------+
30 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: image_diff? Are you suggesting that you define this as a function?

Comment: @therealsix Yes I did say that as the first line in my response and provided all of the code for the functions as an example.

Comment: Sorry not sure how I missed that.

Comment: You would need to use ABS after each subtraction- not just at the end.

Comment: @therealsix Updated.  The real point though is to just use a function that fits the needs against the image information.  Fun problem to solve.

Answer (score 3):

A more "SQLey" way to do this, might be to use a more normalized database approach, with 2 tables:

```
Image(ImageID int, ... other columns as required ...)
ImageZone(ImageID int, ZoneIndex int, ColourValue int, ...)
```

so for your example, you might have

```
ImageID   ZoneIndex   ColourValue
-------   ---------   -----------
  1          1          255
  1          2          255
  ...
  1          9          304
  2          1          255
  ...
  2          9          305
```

Then, to get the distance, something like (I'm a SQL Server guy, but this should be readily translatable to MySQL):

```
 SELECT
    Candidate.ImageID,
    Candidate.ImageFile, /* or whatever... */
    Scores.Difference
 FROM
 (
   SELECT
      Original.ImageID AS OriginalID,
      Candidate.ImageID AS CandidateID,
      SUM(ABS(Original.ColourValue - Candidate.ColourValue)) AS Difference
   FROM ImageZone AS Original
   INNER JOIN ImageZone AS Candidate
     ON (Original.ImageID <> Candidate.ImageID)
     ON (Original.ZoneIndex = Candidate.ZoneIndex)
 ) AS Scores
 INNER JOIN Image AS Candidate ON (Scores.CandidateID = Candidate.ImageID)
 WHERE Scores.OriginalID = 1 /* or the image ID you want to look up */
 ORDER BY Difference
```

So the inner query creates a row for every candidate zone, for example (O = original, C = candidate):

```
 O.ImageID  O.ZoneIndex  O.ColourValue  C.ImageID  C.ZoneIndex  C.ColourValue
 ---------  -----------  -------------  ---------  -----------  -------------
    1           1           255            2            1           255
    ... then ...
    1           9           305            2            9           304
    1           1           255            3            1            99
    ... then ...
    99          9           100           98            9            99
```

which are then aggregated into total differences:

```
 OriginalID  CandidateID  Difference
 ----------  -----------  ----------
    1            2            1
    1            3           10
    ...
    99          98          500
```

You then select from this virtual table, only where OriginalID is 1, and join it back onto the original Image table to get whatever details you need for the lowest 'difference' score (in this case, 2).

This is IMHO a much cleaner DB design (and perfectly suitable if you later use more zones, etc).

Comment: It would be interesting to see the explain plan for this and compare it to the simple plan just using 1 table produces.  My guess is that a compiled function that performs the calculations is more efficient the the dynamic table sub-query but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, from the sounds of it, you are trying to do a form of Sequence alignment. For that there are series of algorithms were are used to compare sequences of genes:

[Sequence Alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_alignment)

Comment: There is a SQL implementation somewhere on Google.

Comment: @webarto - Indeed, I wrote one for SQL Server. I just haven't rewritten it into MySQL. Plenty of options once you know the right tool to use.

Comment: Like they say in my country, there can be no craftsman without tools :) Care to share you function?

Comment: @webarto - More than happy to share but it doesn't make sense in this post as the question is specifically about PHP and MySQL (and I can't remember coming across a question about how to do this in SQL Server).

Comment: If I do this process in php, I can just explode the string and make the calculation. The problem is I need to do it in the SQL query. Also, I'm not sure levenshtein would work, as this is not a perceptual hash of the image. These numbers have meaning: 199 is almost the same as 200. Levenshteing wouln't agree

Comment: @Thomas, I understand, no problem, just curious ;) @HappyDeveloper, anything you can't implement in SQL will be bad for you (server), you are not looking for Levenshtein distance but color similarity. If you change even one value you get totally different color.

Comment: @HappyDeveloper - Well, now you are wanting a fuzzier logic than "how different are they". Is 195 "almost" the same as 200? What about 225? I suppose one solution would be to split the values into a tuple and compare, position by position, the delta across all positions and come up with some sort of weighted average. However, imagine three values where one is the target value. Now suppose one of the values is exact on every position except one where it is 255 instead of 0. Now imagine the other which is off by only one on all positions. Which is closer?

Comment: @HappyDeveloper - As I consider this, this is really a linear algebra problem in comparing or clustering of matrices. I bet there are algorithms for measuring the closeness of matrices which could be used. Will have to do some research...

Comment: Levenshtein is not what you want.  See the solution I posted.

Comment: @Wes, @HappyDeveloper - Certainly just taking the delta position by position is one solution but it doesn't really answer the clustering problem. Consider (0,255x8) and (255,0x8) (the x8 means all other eight positions are that value). Those two values have the same delta but might be consider far more different to each other than (254x9) is to either one individually.

Comment: @Thomas I went strictly by the requirements that @HappyDeveloper posted.  I do agree with what you are saying if he wants a more realistic analysis of the closeness of the match then using levenshtein could be appropriate as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this...

http://kodisha.net/color-names/?color=FD464A

Note the color difference on the right...

```
Color Difference: 1.84568861095
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference

Running this query on 1000+ rows will certainly kill your server if there is a large number of simultaneous users.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so your table images has an id and 9 separate color fields- color1 through color 9

```
SELECT a.id, b.id, ( ABS( a.color1 - b.color ) + ABS( a.color2 + b.color2 ) + ABS( a.color3 + b.color3 ) + ... ) AS difference
FROM images AS a
JOIN images AS b
WHERE a.id > b.id
ORDER BY difference
```

This could be reasonably efficient, you would have to try it.

Comment: Wouldn't this compute all possible "differences" when the original point was to compare a single image node against all other images in the db?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to me **not to be a sequence comparison** problem but a **geography** one.

I think you want to find nearby points in a **9th dimensional** point set.

Check this article on how spatial databases use **R-trees** for efficient searching of clusters (e.g. points nearby which is exactly what you want.): [Incremental Distance Join Algorithms
for Spatial Databases](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.22.4557) (click on the "Cached" link)

Real problem is that I know of no spatial database that supports 9 dimensions. Only hack I could think of would be a triple (A,B,C) of geography triplets of points.

To make my point more clear. Lets have a look at your data:

> The difference between these images is 3:
>
> ```
> 255,255,255,255,255,255,105,195,305
> 255,255,255,255,255,255,107,195,304
> ```

We can look at the above 2 rows as 2 points (lets call them `a` and `b`) in a 9-dimensional world.

The 9 numbers are their coordinates (`a1,a2,...,a9` and `b1,b2,...,b9`).

And the "difference" is their distance: `Sum(|ai-bi|)`. There are many ways to define distance and this is one of the common ones. It's not Euclidean distance but it is similar. And it's slightly more fast to be calculated.

Now, if you are really going to have thousands or millions of images, it's going to be a very slow procedure to calculate all those millions (or trillions) distances. If you just need to compare one at a time, against a few thousands, I think you already have two answers that would be OK.

But if you really want to find similar images and have a lot (like hundreds of thousands) of them stored, R-trees or some other index used by spatial databases will be better. An R-tree is not something magic, it's just an index specialized for this kind of multidimensional data.

If you can't find a spatial database that supports that many dimensions, I'm not sure how a solution of your own would be created.

One thought would be to split the 9 numbers into 3 triplets. Every triplet would be a 3-dimensional point. So, every of your images would be stored as three 3D geography points. Then, the difference between 2 images would be the sum of three (geographic) distances.

Comment: I don't see the difference. I am only comparing each point from one image, to its analogue in the other image.

Comment: I would love to read the article, but the link doesn't work: The supplied document identifier does not match
any document in our repository. Anyway, why do you say that we have 9 dimensions here? I think we can put all the possible colors in a cube (3 dimensions)